# Mожно ли вывести данные конструктора в System.out.println()?

Tags: java

На данный момент задача такая:
Класс `Phone`.
a) Создайте класс `Phone`, который содержит переменные `number`, `model` и `weight`.
б) Создайте три экземпляра этого класса.
в) Выведите на консоль значения их переменных.
Застряла на пункте "B" :(
Сделала суперкласс Phone и три его подкласса. Далее сделала для них конструкторы на основе суперкакласса.
Нужно вывести данные объектов которые были созданы на основе этих классов.
**Можно ли вывести в команде `System.out.println()` эти данные? Или можно как-то по другому это сделать? Заранее спасибо!**

```
public class Phone
{
    int number;
    String model;
    int weight;

    Phone()
    {
    }

    Phone(int number, String model, int weight)
    {
        number = number;
        model = model;
        weight = weight;
    }
}

public class Iphone extends Phone
{
    Iphone(int number, String model, int weight){
        super(number, model, weight);
    }
}
```

и два аналогичных.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Iphone phone1 = new Iphone(1, "odin", 100);
        Phone phone2 = new Nokia(2, "dva", 200);
        Phone phone3 = new Sony(3, "tri", 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: Думаю, имеется в виду вывести с помощью `toString()`. И вообще не идет речь о наследовании. Просят создать 3 инстанса класса `Phone`. Всё

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Но до сих пор интересно можно ли данные конструктора вывести в  System.out.println() :)

Comment: можно..............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Phone
{
int number;
String model;
int weight;

Phone()
{
}

Phone(int number, String model, int weight)
{
    this.number = number;
    this.model = model;
    this.weight = weight;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Phone{" + "number=" + number + ", model='" + model + '\'' + ", weight=" + weight + '}';
}
}
```

---

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Phone phone1 = new Phone(1, "IPhone", 100);
    Phone phone2 = new Phone(2, "Nokia", 200);
    Phone phone3 = new Phone(3, "Sony", 300);

    System.out.println(phone1);
    System.out.println(phone2);
    System.out.println(phone3);
}
}
```